# Round an integer in increments of 5

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math, rounding

I want to increment an integer value in increments of 5. Examples would be: 233 to 235, 437 to 435, and say a corner case such as 298 to 300. I feel like I should divide by 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
((i+2)/5)*5
```

gives the nearest integer multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

(((number/5)*5) + (number-((number/5)*5)>2?5:0))